# Java class filter to load same class of different versions when class referred in custom loader?

Tags: java, filter, classloader

To illustrate the scenario, I have a class called com.test.A and the same class would be modified by different users (eg: DEV1 & DEV2) but they modify their respective classes, eg: com.test.DEV1.A , com.test.DEV2.A

If I use custom loader and load class A, is there any possibility that i can filter the reference of A to DEV1.A or DEV2.A based on some condition?

Comment: can u write the class structures for all the classes in question?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We wish to have a cloud environment common for all the developers but they are free to modify same class but different methods in it the same time. Once development is over, they can be merged.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava It can be any class with 2 methods and each developer works on each method but they are part of one class logically.

Answer (score 1):

Without further knowledge of the problem I would say you are trying to solve this problem in the wrong place.

This looks more like a branching problem, that should be solved in the configuration management level, using the features that your SCM gives you.  Please have a look at this article on how to handle properly different parallel developments https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Source-Control-Done-Right

The tone is quite accessible and I have used it with success in order to introduce branching to teams, I hope you enjoy it

Comment: do you think this can be controlled if there is one development instance and no individual local environment for each developer?

Comment: Even in that case you could try to stablish 2 different continuous integration pipelines (one for each branch) and, for example, different schedules for deployment.  In any case, writing an ad hoc classloader with customized filtering for every class (assuming every programmer in your team touches only 1 class) is working in the wrong direction.  In your case, I would try to branch my development and invest as many resources as possible to get separate individual environments, even taking the risk of mocking any external dependency

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A {
    methodForUser1(params);
    methodForUser2(params);
    ....
    wrapperMethod(params) {
        if (context.user.equals(user1)) 
            methodForUser1(params);
        else if (context.user.equals(user2))
            methodForUser2(params)
        ....
    }
}
```

Now every user only have to call wrapperMethod and it will in turn delegate to the right method you have for the user in context.

This is brute way of doing it. Additionally, you can load the method using reflection.

Another approach could be what @Jorge_B is suggesting in another answer (maintaining different CI pipelines)